# How to improve React performance when change element position with a lots children element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a `div` with mouse move event to change the position(`top`, `left`) but the `div` has a lots child elements.

When child elements count less than 1000 the effect looks good but when counts more than 5000 it's go bad.

What can I do to improve the moving effect performance(I need to show all child elements).

Below is my sample code you can change `const SPAN_COUNT = 5000` to try different counts of child element. BTW, If I code this with pure HTML the performance looks better

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-moon-eid68?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Using css transform to move the element instead of changing the top and left values should increase performance.

Comment: @SteveK you are right, After I post the question I found the transform solution. Do not finish all code the performance is good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the component that you are moving does not need to update (iterate over and create 5000 components) every time it is moved you could possibly make use of React.memo which will make a function component behave similarly to a class component utilising the shouldComponentUpdate shallow compare.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const SPAN_COUNT = 5000;

var spans = Array.from(Array(SPAN_COUNT).keys());

export default function App() {
  const [moving, setMoving] = useState(false);
  const [layerDefaultPosition, setLayerDefaultPosition] = useState();
  const [moveObjectStyle, setMoveObjectStyle] = useState({
    position: "relative",
    top: "0px",
    left: "0px"
  });
  const handleLayerMouseDown = e => {
    setMoving(true);
    const { left, top } = moveObjectStyle;
    setLayerDefaultPosition({
      x: Number(left.split("px")[0]) - e.pageX,
      y: Number(top.split("px")[0]) - e.pageY
    });
  };

  const handleLayerMouseUp = () => {
    setMoving(false);
  };

  const handleLayerMouseMove = e => {
    if (!moving) {
      return;
    }

    const dx = e.pageX + layerDefaultPosition.x;
    const dy = e.pageY + layerDefaultPosition.y;

    const left = `${dx}px`;
    const top = `${dy}px`;

    setMoveObjectStyle({ ...moveObjectStyle, left, top });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{ position: "relative", overflow: "hidden", height: "100vh" }}
    >
      <div
        style={moveObjectStyle}
        onMouseDown={handleLayerMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={handleLayerMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={handleLayerMouseMove}
      >
        <MemoSpans spans={spans} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const Spans = ({spans}) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: "600px", height: "500px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
    >
      {spans.map(x => (
        <span style={{ display: "inline-block", fontSize: "5px" }}>a</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

const MemoSpans = React.memo(Spans);
```

This will stop the 5000 elements being recreated every time the square is moved and only recreate them when the spans property changes (shallow compare).

Comment: Also you'll want to wrap all your event handlers in `useCallback` so they're not re-created every render.

Comment: I try memo it doesn't help

Comment: Sorry, If counts more than 10000 memo help